# evaluating $a^{2009^{2009^{2009^{\text{2009 times}}}}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is to evaluate $$a^{2009^{2009^{2009^{\text{...2009 times}}}}}$$ where $a$ is the complex cube root of unity.

I tried using binomial theorem to find out the last digit of $2009^{2009}$ but couldnot suceed.Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Since 2007 is a multiple of 3, this is equivalent to computing $a^{2^{2^{2^{\text{...2009 times}}}}}$ You just need to compute the remainder of ${2^{2^{2^{\text{...2009 times}}}}}$  when divided by 3.

Comment: Do you mean $(((((a^{2009})^{2009})^{2009})......)$ or $a^{(2009^{(2009....)})}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2009 \equiv - 1 \mod 3$ and $2009^{(2009^{(2009...)})}$ is odd. so $a^{2009^{(2009^{(2009...)})}} = a^{3k - 1} = a^{-1} = a^2= e^{\pi/3 i}$.

$((...(a^{2009})^{2009})^{...})=(((....(a^{-1})^{2009})^{...})= ((...(a^{2009})^{2009})^{...})$ as we raise it an odd number of times $= a^{-1}=e^{\pi/3 i}$ and is the same as above.