# The value of $y=\frac{x}{1+x}$, where $x={{\omega^{2009}}^{2009}}^{. ...\text{upto}\;2009\;\text{times}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

> Let $y=\frac{x}{1+x}$, where 
>   $$x={{\omega^{2009}}^{2009}}^{. ...\text{upto}\;2009\;\text{times}}$$ 
>   and $\omega$ is a complex cube root of $1$. Then $y$ is
>
> $a) \omega;\quad b)-\omega;\quad c)\omega^2; \quad d)-\omega^2.$

***My attempt***:

We have $\omega^{2009}=\omega^2$. Now taking $2009$ power in both side gives ${(\omega^{2009}})^{2009}={(\omega^2)}^{2009}={(\omega^{2009})}^{2}=\omega.$

But ${\omega^{2009}}^{2009}\neq{(\omega^{2009}})^{2009}$, since ${a}^{m^n}\neq a^{mn}$.

I am stuck here. So give me only hints.
(If it is required to change the tags of the problem then please feel free to change it)

Comment: The value of $\omega^n$ depends only on the residue of $n$ modulo 3. The value of $2009^m$ modulo 3 depends only on the residue of $m$ modulo 2.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251030/evaluating-a200920092009-text2009-times?rq=1

Comment: Ok.. I understood. Thanks

Comment: If you understand, Saheb, let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes. It will be greatful if you post as an answer.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, Saheb, you have to put @Gerry in it. But I thought that you understaood how to do the problem, which is why I encouraged *you* to write up and post an answer.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, Saheb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $2009 \equiv - 1(mod\;3)$. Also ${{{2009}^{2009}}^{2009}}^{...}$ is odd.

Therefore $${{2009}^{2009}}^{. …\text{upto}\;2009\;\text{times}}\equiv - 1(mod\;3).$$
$\therefore{{2009}^{2009}}^{. …\text{upto}\;2009\;\text{times}}=3k-1$ for some integer $k$.

Thus $$x={{\omega^{2009}}^{2009}}^{. …\text{upto}\;2009\;\text{times}}=\omega^{3k-1}=\omega^{-1}=\omega^2.$$

$$\therefore y=\frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{\omega^2}{1+\omega^2}=\frac{\omega^2}{-\omega}=-\omega.$$